# Any Solution for jakarta.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.ecommerce.Ecommerce.entity.ProductCategory with id 1

Tags: jpa

I'm facing the above issue, however, I'm confident that the fields are not empty as I've run the script in MySQL, and there I can see the entries in the table but when I try to hit the API I encounter those entries are not displayed.

[image: Product.java and Product Category.java]

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors